# How to transparently redirect a user without rewriting URL when page does not exist?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a node web app with nginx acting as a proxy.

Here's the `server` block for that site :

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name subdomain.example.org;

        location / {
                # Offline handling
                error_page https://example.org/502

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567;
                proxy_redirect off;

                # Socket.io Support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

If the web app ever goes down, then the `error_page` directive sends the user off-site, but the url ends up changing. Is it possible to send the user to that site, but maintain the same url in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

As the [doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) says :

> If there is no need to change URI during internal redirection it is
>   possible to pass error processing into a named location:

```
location / {
    error_page 404 = @fallback; }

location @fallback { 
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

You would also need to put `on` the [proxy_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) directive.

Also, to respect the URL format you give in your example (`https://example.org/502`), i had to use a `$folder` variable.

Finally, you will have to setup the [resolver](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive.

To conclude, you will have something like this :

```
location / {
   proxy_intercept_errors on;
   error_page 404 = @fallback;
   proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:4567;
   ...
   ...
}

location @fallback {
   resolver 8.8.8.8;   # <-- Put your own DNS Server here
   set $folder "502";
   proxy_pass https://example.org/$folder/;
}
```